# Reset RXJS interval and hide field when form control value changes Angular 12

Tags: angular, functional-programming, rxjs, dom-events

Expected behavior:

Reset interval when input value changes. When interval reaches 0 hide element in the dom.

My implementation does not consistently restart the interval. I believe the issue is because the value changes observable only fires off when the input value is a distinct values. I have add a Stackblitz to show the behavior. Any help is greatly appreciated.

View

```
<input [formControl]="inputFC">
```

Controller

```
public inputFC: FormControl = new FormControl('', []);

public counter$ = interval(1000).pipe(
 mapTo(-1), // subtract from timer
 scan((accumulator, current) => {
  return accumulator + current;
 }, 3),
 takeWhile(value => {
  return value >= 0;
 }),
 map(value => {
  this.hide = (value >= 0);
  return value;
 }),
 repeatWhen(() => this.inputFC.valueChanges));

public input$ = this.inputFC.valueChanges.pipe(throttle(() => this.counter$));
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-interval-form-control?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

There're a couple of things:

- With `this.hide = (value >= 0)` `hide` will always be `true` because the last value passed by `takeWhile` is `1`. When the counter reaches `0` it will swallow the value and complete the chain.
- `takeWhile` accepts an optional argument that tells `takeWhile` to pass the last value that didn't pass the predicate function. So you can use it like this `takeWhile(value => value >= 0, true)`.
- `throttle()` will unsubscribe from `this.counter$` after its first emission and then subscribe again when the form value changes. This means that you don't need to use `repeatWhen` at all and the timer will reset automatically.
- For sideeffects it's better to use `tap()` for convinience. When using timers in Angular you might need in some situations trigger change detection manually.

So I'm not sure what exactly you want to do but I guess this could be fairly close and hopefuly you'll get the idea how it works.

```
public counter$ = interval(1000).pipe(
  mapTo(-1), // subtract from timer
  scan((accumulator, current) => accumulator + current, 3),
  takeWhile(value => value >= 0, true),
  tap(value => this.hide = (value > 0)),
  filter(value => value === 0), // only when the timer reaches `0` we'll disable `throttle`'s timer and it'll unsubscribe.
);

public input$ = this.inputFC
  .valueChanges
  .pipe(
    map(value => value.substr(value.length - 1)),
    throttle(() => this.counter$)
  );
```

Your updated live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-interval-form-control-qquuyb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts